# How can I make a gsap animation that slides div from outside of screen into the right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gsap

Its my first time working with gsap / greensock and using the animations. I'm trying to transform the X position of a certain DIV so it slide in the screen from the right. The weird thing is that with the same code half of the time it slides the correct div in from the right but the other half of the time it seems to randomly slide which I think is the section from the left and everything looks buggy.

This is the code I have:

```
<section class="homepage">

    <div class="TV">
      <h1">TV</h1>
    </div>

 </section>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            gsap.from('.TV', {duration: 1, x: 1400});
              gsap.to('.TV', {duration: 1, x: 0});
      </script>
```

Sorry if its a stupid question but its my first time working with gsap and I don't seem to understand why it works half of the time but the other half it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have two tweens that are attempting to control the same properties of the same element at the same time.

To fix it, simply remove the .to tween.

Another alternative is to use a .fromTo tween.

Also keep in mind that you can use viewport units like x: "100vw" or use a percentage of the element's width like xPercent: 100

I highly recommend going through GSAP's [Getting Started article](https://greensock.com/get-started/).